# FIltering Adult Content

Tags: opendns

I'm using OpenDNS now for over a month . But  it doesn't filter Adult Content although i specified High Restriction in the settings . It automatically sends the IP to its server (?) but it doesn't filter .

Any alternative to this ? I'm looking to filter only Porn content....

Any suggestions welcome......

Note : Related questions may exist in superuser. But no answers to them.

Comment: What you're asking for is effectively impossible without using a whitelist of known-good sites, I'm afraid. That's not to say you can't try and do better, but in my experience oDNS is among the best.

Comment: I don't know what OpenDNS is maybe it's a webbrowser; but normally your webbrowser will also give you some security features/ "Parent" control that may help ie Internet Explorer (dare I say it) yes you may have to block sites as well but you can do this as needed.  Just a thought!

Comment: It's not a web browser ... It's a content filtering service based on  DNS ( domain naming system ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative would be K9 Web Protection is a kid's web filtering and blocking software that is extremely configurable. It has filtering, word block, site block, category block, time limits/restrictions and also blocks ads.  I've used it to help block content like you're requesting...

It works cross-browsers; one configuration covers Internet Explorer, Firefox, and others all one the same machine.

K9 Web Protection: http://www1.k9webprotection.com/

For Windows only, and works very well (free).  Installs separately - not as an addon, and all configurations are protected by a password...

Comment: I installed it . It works just fine....Thank you.

Comment: no problem @vettipayyan, glad to help!

Answer (score 5):

I have not seen a situation where OpenDNS filtering does not work.

Are you sure you are actually using OpenDNS/did you set your routers or machines DNS correctly?

Comment: definitely sounds like a config issue...

Comment: yes i do...If i manually update the OpenDNS updater , it works....Although the updater says last update is 36 mins ago

Comment: @vettipayyan, you have to do more than run the updater for OpenDNS to work.  Are you sure you have completed the configuration correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There are hardware solutions (i.e. www.koalasafe.com) now that have a few benefits over OpenDNS or software solutions.
You can choose which devices to protect in the home, monitor and set schedules on a per device basis and much more without the need to configure every device in the home.